# If a figure is too large and with parameter [H], LaTeX skips a page

Tags: floats, page-breaking

If a figure is too large for one page and bound with the parameter [H], LaTeX leaves an entire page blank. Using the `[p!]` placement prevents the empty page but messes up the order. The first page of the result is blank and the figure then appears on the second page. The second figure should be placed *before* the text "Text after the second figure", but it isn't.
Why would LaTeX leave a page entirely blank? Using `[p!]` instead of `[H]` clearly is no real solution. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[40pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption.}
\end{figure}
Text after the first figure.
\newpage
\begin{figure}[p!]
    \caption{This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption. This is a really long caption.}
\end{figure}
Text after the second figure.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you are telling it to using `H`. Try reducing the figure to fit in the page and use `\begin{figure}[htp]`.

Comment: Thats the point: I don't want to reduce the figures size.

Comment: Do give `\begin{figure}[p!]` a try.

Comment: The `[H]` placement specifier is almost always more trouble than it's worth. Learn to live with LaTeX's float placement algorithm and, if you still feel you must override it from time to time, don't use `[H]`; instead, use `[ht!]` for smaller `table` and `figure` objects and `[p!]` for full-page objects.

Comment: This solves the problem about the empty page but I did use `H` for a reason: The figure is to be placed there in the document and not anywhere else.

Comment: Just put the content there, without the figure-environment. Use the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package, if you need a caption.

Comment: This brings us back to the empty page.

Comment: Well, maybe you should describe your difficulties in more detail. Are you trying to write a very long caption in 40pt font size, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @LukasFun - Your objective, "[t]he figure is to be placed there in the document and not anywhere else", is *impossible to achieve* if the `figure` occupies a full page (or even more, as you wrote). No amount of foot-stomping is going to change this fact. As you probably (hopefully?) know, `figure` environments *cannot* be broken across pages. The best you can do in such a case is to place the `figure` on a page by itself, via `[p!]`. That's also why I recommend you stay away from using the `[H]` placement specifier: if it "works", `[ht!]` works *at least as well*.

Comment: @DG' This is just an example of a figure that doesn't really fit on a page. I am trying to write a long caption in a smaller fontsize though, the 40pt in the example are just there to give a short minimal example.

Comment: @LukasFun - Captions are not supposed to be long running texts... I am still not getting, what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: @Mico The point is that clearly the figure _can_ be placed somewhere and I just don't get why there would be an empty page if the figure is placed where it is supposed to be. If  I use `[p!]` the figure gets placed on its own page, but it no longer is where it is supposed to be - text in the document that is supposed to be placed after the figure now gets placed before it.

Comment: @LukasFun: Is it the figure + caption that is larger than the textheight or does the figure not fit onto a page that is already partially filled with text? Please clarify. Other options besides decreasing the image size might be changing the text before the image, shortening the caption or changing the margins of the pages.

Comment: @leandriis There is no other text on the page, the figure and its caption are there alone.

Comment: @LukasFun (regarding your reply to my comment): My suggestion to reduce the size of the figure was because if you use `h` or `H`, LaTeX will try to put the figure where you asked it to; if it can't, it will try on the next page. However, if in the first try the figure didn't fit (in the empty page) because it was too large, LaTeX will also move to the next. The problem with `H` is that instead of filling that page with text, LaTeX will leave a blank page, which is what you are seeing. If you reduce the figure to fit the page (afterall, it doesn't make much sense otherwise), it will work fine.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the reply. The reason I am confused is because Latex is able to place the figure on the second page. If so, why wouldn't it place it on the first page right away? It is able to place it on a page with `[p!]` so why not on an empty page?

Comment: Look at the warnings. I bet you have complaints about an overfull box or similar. The figure doesn't really fit but, if starting a new page doesn't help, LaTeX will output it anyway as it can't do any better than that. Note that LaTeX needs it to fit the *page* - not the paper. Is the figure wider than `\textwidth` or longer than `\textheight`?

Comment: @LukasFun Quoting Don Knuth: "computers don't understand things the way people do (at least not yet)". When LaTeX tryes to put your figure with `H` it will measure the size of the figure and the _available_ page size. Since the figure is larger than the page it will deduce "okay, this doesn't fit here; I'll move to the next page", and then places it there unconditionally. The first condition could have been met if there was no space at all in the first page or if the page was entirely blank, as is the case. Why do you _need_ to explode the margins with your figure?

Comment: @cfr You're right, there is. The figure is larger than `\textheight`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The reason why I need or want to explode the margins with my figure shouldn't matter. I just want to know wether there is any way to get my figure where I want it to be without changing its size.

Comment: @LukasFun You're right, it doesn't matter. Wrap the whole thing in `\vbox to\textheight{...}` and it will fit one way or another, if that's what you want.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Not *need*, maybe, but this is sometimes the best solution. If a diagram wants to be large, using the entire page area is often preferable in terms of legibility and convenience. The alternative may reduce legibility or clarity.

Comment: The trick as @PhelypeOleinik says, is to lie. You tell LaTeX that the figure fits and it will believe you. Just remember that you won't get any warnings in this case, so you have to make sure it really does fit yourself. Alternatively, you can alter the page layout for a page. You'll also want to suppress headers and footers. I generally go for the lying approach (with header and footer suppression) rather than messing around with the layout.

Comment: You state, "I just want to know wether there is any way to get my [oversized] `figure` where I want it to be." We agree that due to its very large size, the only possible placement of this `figure` is on a page all by itself, right? To place it, then, on the specific page that *you* believe it should be placed, you could (a) switch the placement specifier from `[H]` to `[p!]` and (b) move up the occurrence of the whole `figure` code block within the tex file. Only you know how much further up within the text file the `figure` code block needs to be.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, that does everything I was hoping for. Are you going to write this into an answer?

Comment: @LukasFun Sorry, but no. Using that construction in LaTeX (especially around a `figure` environment) is a really bad idea, so I prefer not to answer that. You may add yourself an answer with that. (P.S.: A tiny bit better than the `\vbox`: `\parbox[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}{...}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this is intended to happen. If there is a floating environment that doesn't fit on the page it is supposed to be on, LaTeX places it on the next, even if that leaves a completely empty page.

There is a workaround for this though: To trick LaTeX into believing that the object fits! I was told this should not be used as standard since there will be no warning if anything goes wrong in the process.
But here it is:

To get the object placed exactly where you want it with no weird empty pages in the process, use this:

```
\parbox[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}{
    The stuff that you want to be here
}
```